# Why can 言ってんじゃねーぞ be an order?

Tags: auxiliaries

I've been learning japanese for quite a while and always wondered why :

> 言ってんじゃねえぞ

could be an order. Whereas something like :

> 言わない

can't be an order.

Because basically, 【言ってんじゃねぞ】 is just :

> 言う　の　テ形
>
> 助動詞　いる not pronounced since it's a contraction
>
> Contraction of the particle の (ん)
>
> And じゃない

So I don't understand why 【○○てんじゃねえぞ】can be understood as :

"Don't ***"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the contraction 言ってんじゃねぇぞ, you get 言っているのではないぞ as you say, which is a のだ form negated. Now, a のだ form can be used as a virtual order and its negative form can be prohibition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you say "now" so wasn't it the case before? Why that change? And what do you mean by "a virtual order"? I have never seen an order in 【のだ】 
And if I say like 【勉強するのではないよ】 or 【勉強するんじゃないよ】, can it be understood as an order? To me it doesn't sound like it is at all, I would rather say 【勉強するな】... thanks!